# An electron is moving with a velocity of $0.85c$ in the same direction as that of a moving photon. What is the relative velocity?

Tags: special-relativity, photons, electrons, inertial-frames, velocity

I recently encountered a question which asks,

> An electron is moving with a velocity of $0.85c$ in the same direction as that of a moving photon. What is the relative velocity of the electron with respect to the photon?

The velocity addition law from Theory of relativity is given by,

$$\frac{u+v}{1+\frac{uv}{c^2}}$$

which calculates the relative velocity of a particle with velocity, $v$ with respect to another particle with velocity, $u$. If they are opposite in direction then the formula is,

$$\frac{u-v}{1-\frac{uv}{c^2}}$$

As the electron and the photon is moving in the same direction so it is obvious that the photon will see the electron moving forward with it! And using the above formula I calculated out the relative velocity to be same as the photon! No matter what velocity the other particle has the photon will always see it having the velocity same as c moving forward with it.
But the answer is given $-c$!  I don't get why the negative sign is there! Why the photon will see the electron to move backward with velocity $c$?

Comment: A photon can't see ,a frame of reference at speed of light is not possible

Comment: @Theasgardian I disagree that the reference frame does not exits. It is however singular in the sense that it is non-inverable and sends all other space time points to infnity.

Comment: @Mikael Fremling  : If you want to measure speed of a particle for example ,you need to calculate the distance traveled and devide it by time taken.A photon does not experience time ,how would a photon calculate a velocity of another particle?

Comment: @Theasgardian It is true that photons cannot meassure time. But anything moving slower than the speed of light can, and in this case the the limit $v\to c$ can be taken smoothly for exeperienced velocities. The answer (see my answer) is that everything look like it's receding at the speed of light  in the limit $v\to c$.

Answer (score 3):

This is a case of choosing the wrong reference frame, most likely. From the electrons point of view, the photon is moving away with velocity $c$, since it is light.
Conversely, from the photon point of view the electron will be moving away with velocity $-c$.

Note however the somewhat singular behavior that the photon will consider everything else (in 1D) to either move with velocity $c$ or $-c$ depending if it is moving away or towards the photon.

To see that this is actually the case consider the Lorenz transformations
\begin{eqnarray*}
t^{\prime} & = & \gamma\left(t-\frac{vx}{c^{2}}\right)\\
x^{\prime} & = & \gamma\left(x-vt\right).
\end{eqnarray*}

Let us now take the pathological limit of lettering $v\to c$. This has a profound effect on the $\gamma$ and sends $\gamma\to\infty$. However is we do not evaluate the $\gamma$, we simply get that

\begin{eqnarray*}
t^{\prime} & = & \gamma\left(t-\frac{x}{c}\right)\\
x^{\prime} & = & \gamma\left(x-ct\right).
\end{eqnarray*}

Comparing the $t^{\prime}$ and $x^{\prime}$ we find that
$$ct^{\prime}=\gamma\left(tc-x\right)=-x^{\prime}.$$

Thus, every other space-time point looks like it is receding from the light with velocity

$$ \frac{x^{\prime}}{t^{\prime}}=-c $$

Had one chosen $v\to-c$ (light going the other way) in the above, one would have obtained an answer with the opposite sign.

$$ \frac{x^{\prime}}{t^{\prime}}=+c $$

Comment: After some surprising downvotes i added some math to support my answer.

Comment: I kind of understand the downvotes. Considering the photon frame of reference is not useful or makes absolutely no sense, aside from getting intuition from this pathological derivation (in the mathematical sense).

Comment: @Mauricio. Well It was the OP and not me who wanted to talk about the reference frame of the light ("No matter what velocity the other particle has the photon will always see it having the velocity same as c moving forward with it."). I just clarified the situation.